# hiding the polygons or Setting the zOrder of the polygon in box2d

Tags: iphone, ios, box2d-iphone

I have downloaded the demo from the Ray Wenderlich tutorial. Now I am making the polygons with it and I am unable to know actually where the zOrder to be set for the Polygons. My background has -1 as zOrder so it shows the PINK color polygon over the background. If I am setting the Background zOrder to 0 it doesn't show the Polygons. Actually I want to make the Polygon's zOrder to -100 so that I would be able to workout completely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the OpenGL debug drawing comment or remove any flags set to the debug draw.
Do this somewhere in your init method:

```
debugDraw = new GLESDebugDraw( PTM_RATIO );
world->SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);
uint32 flags = 0;
//flags += b2DebugDraw::e_shapeBit;
debugDraw->SetFlags(flags);
```